# Array Dimension

Tags: arrays, r, keras

I am currently learning to use Keras in R. When I run the command

```
dim(mnist$train$x)
```

I get the output as (output 1)

```
[1] 60000 28 28
```

which means that there are 60000 matrices each with a 28*28 dimension.

Now when I create an array through R code for the same dimension , I use

```
test <- array(28*28*6000,dim=c(28,28,6000))
```

where the inner layers are specified first and upon using the statement `dim(test)` I get this output (output 2)

```
[1]   28   28 6000
```

Both these notations are showing up the same array in different format. Is it possible to get the output in the second case in the output 1 format ?

Comment: is there a reason you're not using `dim=c(6000, 28,28)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want output 2 in output 1 format? You mean something like this:

```
test <- array(28*28*6000,dim=c(28,28,6000))

d <- dim(test)

newdim <- c(d[length(d)], d[-length(d)] )
```

newdim will be `60000 28 28`